# AJAX call fails with SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sorry for making a post with a generic error but I just can't figure this out!  I have an ajax call that for now sends an empty object and just returns json_encode(array('status' => 'success')); while I'm debugging. The ajax call is failing with Error in ajax call.  Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I've tried sending just data['pid']='csv' in case the json needed to have something in it, but still get the same error.

AJAX call

```
function runDataDownload() {
    var data = {};
  //  data['rawFiles'] = $('#projectIDs').val(); 
  //  data['metadata'] = $('#getData').val();
  //  data['type']=  $('#submitType').val();
  //  data['pid']='csv';
  //  data['command']='data/qcTest';
console.log(data);
console.log(typeof data)
    var qcRunId="csv" + Date.now();
    var posturl = baseURL + "manage/ajax_runBg/csv/" + qcRunId;
    $.ajax({type: "POST", url: posturl, data: data, dataType: 'json'})
            .done(function(result) {
                console.log(result);  

                if (result.status==='success'){ 
                    // begin checking on progress                     
                    checkRunStatus(qcRunId, loopIndex);                   
               }
                else if (result.status==='failed'){ 
                   $('#' + errorId + ' > li').remove();                                                
                   $.each(result.errors, function(key, value) {
                       $('#' + errorId).append( "<li>" + value + "</li>" );
                   });                                                
                   $('#' + statusId).hide();                    
                   $('#' + errorId).show(); 
                }
                else {
                   $('#' + errorId + ' > li').remove();  
                   $('#' + errorId).append( "<li>Invalid return from ajax call</li>" );  
                   $('#' + errorId).show(); 
                   // PTODO - may not be needed
                   // make sure it is visible
                   $('#' + errorId).get(0).scrollIntoView();
               }           
            }) 
                .fail(function(jqXHR, status, err) { 
                    console.log(jqXHR + status + err);
                    $('#' + errorId + ' > li').remove();  
                    $('#' + errorId).append( `<li>Error in ajax call.  Error: ${status} (${err.name}: ${err.message})</li>`);                          
                    $('#' + errorId).show(); 

            });  
}
```

And my php code:

```
    public function ajax_runBg($qcName, $runId) {
         echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check the response in the Network tab of your developer console, it most likely is not returning the proper json

Comment: it says "This request has no response data available."

Comment: status code is 200

Comment: Interesting update- I copied the ajax_runBg code into a different controller and it worked!   I really want it in the first controller, though (my colleague calls the same code from the first controller so right now it's duplicated in both controllers).  Any ideas why the code would work in one controller and not the other?

Comment: where are you calling ajax_runBg ?

Comment: Status code 200 just means the server didn't throw an error. I can return empty responses with status code 200 all day.

"This request has no response data available," indicates that the server is not returning anything, much less a valid JSON response.

Comment: I think the problem is you're getting the php notice message in response.

Comment: I'm calling ajax_runBg from a .js file...

Comment: Which PHP framework do you use? If PHP is the source of the error, try [setting up Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) and [step through](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug) your PHP code.

Comment: `baseURL + "manage/ajax_runBg/csv/" + qcRunId` seems to be only passing 1 parameter to the route, whereas `ajax_runBg()` expects 2.  Maybe that's throwing an error, so your response never happens, but something about your framework is preventing a 500 response, and `display_errors` is off so you're not seeing any problems.  Anything in your framework/PHP/web server logs?

Comment: when I have this it's usually a problem with the back-end. check your server error logs. e.g. /var/log/apache/error.log or similar. your framework might hide the error to the client.

Comment: Update your PHP to >=7.3

Comment: You can check followings: 1. Check that you added `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");` in your backend API. You can check it response header in chrome browser dev tool. 2. Check if invisible character is printed at front and  end in backend. 3.  Check if you specified `dataType: 'json',` in your ajax call. 4.

Comment: I finally figured it out!  The reason the code was working in my controller was that my colleagues controller had authentication in the constructor!  So there must have been an authentication error returned, that was not JSON formatted, hence the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment an answer in case someone else runs into this-

The reason the code was working in my controller was that my colleague's controller had authentication checks in the constructor! So there must have been an authentication error returned, that was not JSON formatted, hence the error..

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to clear the PHP output buffer after *ajax_runBg* has been called. Check this by adding `ob_flush(); flush();` to *ajax_runBg* after the echo statement.

Comment: would I see output from ob_flush() / flush()?  I don't see it in the normal logging location.

Comment: You would see it in the network tab of the developer tools where it now says "This request has no response data available." PHP saves some amount of data until it has a bunch together and only then sends it. But depending on what happens this can be again deleted from the so called "output buffer" which I guessed happened here. With `ob_flush(); flush();`you force PHP to send whatever it has collected so far. But if the request still has no response it's probalby another cause.

Comment: request still has no response :(

Comment: It turned out to be a PHP problem. Please provide more info about the invloved PHP! (as mentioned also in comment to question). Do it by editing the question and add maybe the surrounding PHP there, not in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for making an answer, when i don't have a full one, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I ran this code (i removed variables that i don't have) and did not get an error (nothing wrong with "echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));").

Here are some possible reasons why it fails:
Your problem could be that the php does not echo anything.

I once got this problem and fixed it by first making a variable out of json_encode("stuff to encode") and then doing echo on that variable.

Is there more to the php file that you did not show? There could be a problem if there are other things being echoed.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right, than you have to specify the key and the value in data attr. .

```
var data = {};
 data['rawFiles'] =$('#projectIDs').val(); 
 data['metadata'] = $('#getData').val();
  data['type']=  $('#submitType').val();
  data['pid']='csv';
   data['command']='data/qcTest'
```

... Ajax...
Data: {dataKey: data}
....
And in the API you can catch it with dataKey name.

Answer (score -1):

When sending json you must first encode it as json, so:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: posturl, data: JSON.stringify(data), dataType: 'json'})
```

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: I was sending no data in my test...so I would be stringifying nothing.